# How to set progress image and Track image for progress bar in swift?

Tags: swift

I Want to set progress image and Track image for progress bar But i unable to do it, Here I give code in objective-C so some one give idea for set image in progress view in swift.

```
[progressView setTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"track"]]; 
[progressView setProgressImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"progress"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swift, since it already has setters and getters, setting variables is done with,

```
progressView.trackImage = UIImage(named: "track")
```

You can get the value of a variable using

```
let trackImage = progressView.trackImage
```

Similar for any other variable of any other library.

Comment: Hi Rishi but it is not implement in iphone 6?

Comment: I did not get what you meant?

Comment: Track image is set but it run only in simulator not in device, what can i do?

Comment: That would be some problem in some other part of your code. Not this.